# Uniform Convergence of Sequence of Functions Doubt

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

For the sequence of functions $$f_n={nx\over 1+n^3x^3},x\in[0,1]$$ If we wish to check the Uniform Convergence. I tried doing it in the following two ways

**Method 1 :**

$\lim f_n=0=f(x)$ , for a given $\epsilon>0$

$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|{nx\over 1+n^3x^3}-0|={nx\over 1+n^3x^3}<{nx\over n^3x^3}={1\over n^2x^2}<\epsilon$

so we have , the result holds good for $n>{1\over x \sqrt{\epsilon}}$but, as $x\rightarrow 0, m\rightarrow\infty $. Tis means that $f_n$ is not uniformly convergent

**Method 2:** Using $M_n-test$

let $y={nx\over 1+n^3x^3},y'={n(1-n^3x^2)\over (1+n^3x^2)^4}$. Setting $y'=0, y={1\over n^{3/2}}$ This is the maximum value as confirmed by $y''$. As $M_n\rightarrow 0 \ as  \ n\rightarrow\infty $,  The function must be Uniformly convergent.

So where am i doing/understanding it wrong ?

Comment: The first method is OK.  You've shown that the '$n$' depends on the choice of '$x$', which violates the definition of uniform convergence.  Doing the trick of evaluating the $f_n$'s at the values $\frac{1}{n}$ just gives you something to point at and makes the argument more concrete.

Comment: @tylerc0816 yes, but that would imply that the given function is not Uniformly convergent. But in the question it is required to prove that it is uniformly convergent ?, do you think there is a problem with the question ?

Comment: Your question asks to 'check uniform convergence', which is slightly vague.  I take that to mean 'check whether or not the sequence of functions is uniformly convergent.'  If the question asked to *verify* uniform convergence, that would be a different matter.  You can show using the hint in my answer that the sequence does *not* converge uniformly on $[0, 1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: The functions converge pointwise to $0$, and $$ f_n\left( \frac{1}{n} \right) = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: I understand that $f_n$ converges point-wise to $0$, i cannot relate with the second hint though. Are we reducing the inequality further removing $x$ ?

Comment: I am actually concerned about the mistake i am making in proving it using the definition.

Comment: Using the second line, you can show that the distance $\| f_n - f \|$ is bounded away from $0$ at certain points.  Thus, the convergence is not uniform on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: okie, what is wrong with what i have done ?

Comment: I've only seen an '$M_n$-test' (a.k.a. Weierstrass $M$-test) to show uniform convergence of a series of functions, so I'm not sure what you are doing in the second method.  Also, the derivative is $$ \frac{n - 2n^4x^3}{(1 + n^3x^3)^2} $$

Comment: I have used the same $M-test$ you are talking about in the second method. What is wrong with the first method ?